# Mqtt - controlling publish for clients

Tags: mqtt, publish-subscribe, mosquitto

If there 4 clients that publish audio stream to a topic and are also subscribed to it, is it possible to restrict publishing for other clients when one client is publishing. More like a push-to-talk service.

Comment: Your clients must publish to 2 topics - one topic for the audio stream itself and another topic for who is currently streaming. Then the clients must implement a new behavior "listen before talking" - if another client pushes to topic 2 then the currently streaming client should stop streaming. If the currently streaming client pushs "stopped" to topic 2 - then any of the other clients can start streaming after a short (and **random**) delay. This is exactly how Ethernet works - the random delay is to reduce the risk of collision (simultaneous talking).

Comment: Will implement this solution. Thank you